# Could not find ag-grid-angular/main folder in node_modules

Tags: angularjs, npm, ag-grid

We are integrating ag-grid in angular 4
Below are the dependencies in package.json
"ag-grid": "10.0.x",
"ag-grid-angular": "10.0.x"
did npm install it downloaded above modules without main folder

and from app.module.ts - we have added

import {AgGridModule} from "ag-grid-angular/main"; - in every refereence example we are seeing this line but there is no main folder in library.

error:

"(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/ag-grid-angular/main

please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have an issue with your systemjs config.

There is excellent documentation on how to use the grid on the ag-grid website:

https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-angular-systemjs/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0

Comment: have you considered that op did in fact read the manual before asking for help. RTM is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

run:

```
npm install
```

in the root folder followed by

```
npm audit fix
```